# Order string as number in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

using $filter in controller to sort list of json data by price and added date, in the json data price is stored as string instead of number. I want to sort them by price first then added date,
sample angular code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5wkvzbgt/7/

```
$scope.results = $filter('orderBy')($scope.results, ['-price','added']);
```

Comment: So why you don't convert them to numbers on data get?

Comment: json data is just sample. i will not aware what json data i get from backend. json columns may change also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to your expression argument and use it to parse the string to a number. Setting the 3rd parameter to true reverse the results:

```
$scope.results = $filter('orderBy')($scope.results, 
                             [function(a){ return parseInt(a.price); },'-added']);
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/to2r0fpg/1/)

Comment: Looks good, but doesnt work when sort 'price' as asc and 'added' as desc.

Comment: Sorry, you want to sort by price 'asc' and added 'desc'?

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do desc sort using the function? i mean for string is it possible to sort desc with the function?